# phonegap android ajax call not appending data

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm new to phonegap and android. I am trying to create a project which fetch pages/data from webserver but it is not working. The code i have used is shown below, facing problem in appending data from ajax call.

when application starts in emulator it shows the alert with all data fetched from local server but its not appending to #resultBlock

here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script>


function onDeviceReady() {
    $('#resultBlock').html('Loading');
    $.ajax({
  url: 'http://192.168.1.2/user/welcome/',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#resultBlock').html(data);
    alert(data);
  }
});

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);       
});

</script>
</head>
<body >
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   


        <h3>Result</h3>
        <p id="resultBlock"></p>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hake sure the js files are included correctly and that the path is correct. then use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'http://192.168.1.2/user/welcome/functions.php', 
                data: { get_param: 'candidates' },
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) { 
                     $('#resultBlock').html(data);
                                     alert(data);
                }, 
                error: function () { 
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest.errorThrown); 
                } 

            });
});
```